# How to combine two same lengths array into one same length array with element joined by a separator

Tags: javascript

Given

```
a=["a", "b", "c"];
x=["x", "y", "z"];
```

combine/join the two list: the expected result:

```
ax=["a:x", "b:y", "c:z"];
```

How? One liner is better.

Something like python's zip function.

Thanks

Comment: Search for `zip` or `zipWith`.

Comment: Maybe a loop? Or is that too crazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES6:

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c"], 
    x = ["x", "y", "z"]; 
let ax = a.map( (value,index) => value + ':' + x[index] ); 

console.log(ax);
```

Comment: I wanted something similar as python's zip function; however, this one is one liner. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
a=["a", "b", "c"];
x=["x", "y", "z"];

var ax = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ax.push(a[i] + ":" + x[i]);
}

console.log(ax);

// Output:
// [ 'a:x', 'b:y', 'c:z' ]
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `Math.min(a.length, x.length)`

Comment: "How to combine two **same lengths array** into..."